# Entity Framework Core: FromSqlInterpolated(). An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Id

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-7.0, ef-core-7.0

I want to get a list of my friends' stories. It didn't work through LINQ, but I was able to write a good SQL query that really works and returns what I need. I use .NET 7 & EF Core 7.

```
int userId = 1;
StoryContainerRto test = await _context.StoryContainer
                .FromSqlInterpolated($@"SELECT s."Id", s."AuthorId", u."Id", u."AccountHeaderUrl", u."AvatarUrl", u."Description", u."Email", u."IsAuthorOfQualityContent", u."IsDeleted", u."IsInShadowBan", u."IsVerifiedProfile", u."LinkInBio", u."MedalsAmount", u."Name", u."Nickname", u."PasswordHash", u."PasswordSalt", u."PhoneNumber", u."PhoneNumberPrefix", u."PhoneNumberVerefied", u."RegistrationDateTime", u."TelegramId", u."TelegramVerifyingChatId"
                        FROM ""StoryContainer"" as s
                        INNER JOIN ""StoryContentRefs"" as scr ON scr.""StoryId"" = s.""Id""
                        LEFT JOIN ""User"" as u ON u.""Id"" = s.""AuthorId""
                        LEFT JOIN ""StoryContentRefRtoUserRto"" as whoView ON whoView.""ViewedId"" = {userId} AND whoView.""ViewedStoriesId"" = scr.""Id"" 
                        WHERE s.""AuthorId"" IN (
                            SELECT u.""Id""
                            FROM ""UserFriend"" as f, ""User"" as u
                            WHERE
                                CASE
                                    WHEN f.""FirstUserFriendId"" = {userId}
                                    THEN f.""SecondUserFriendId"" = u.""Id""
                                    WHEN f.""SecondUserFriendId"" = {userId}
                                    THEN f.""FirstUserFriendId"" = u.""Id""
                                END
                        )
                        AND scr.""CreateTimestamp"" >= NOW() - '1 day'::INTERVAL
                        AND scr.""IsDelete"" = false").ToListAsync();
```

Output:

> System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: Id

If you execute this code, the SQL query will be identical (given that the SQL query is lightweight. It just gets the story and the author, but does not get the rest of the information, because it is needed only for clarity)

```
StoryContainerRto entity = await _context.StoryContainer
                .AsNoTracking()
                .Include(e => e.Author)
                .Where(e => e.AuthorId == 1)
                .ToListAsync();
```

Generated SQL (note the duplication of the "Id" column):

```
SELECT s."Id", s."AuthorId", u."Id", u."AccountHeaderUrl", u."AvatarUrl", u."Description", u."Email", u."IsAuthorOfQualityContent", u."IsDeleted", u."IsInShadowBan", u."IsVerifiedProfile", u."LinkInBio", u."MedalsAmount", u."Name", u."Nickname", u."PasswordHash", u."PasswordSalt", u."PhoneNumber", u."PhoneNumberPrefix", u."PhoneNumberVerefied", u."RegistrationDateTime", u."TelegramId", u."TelegramVerifyingChatId"
FROM "StoryContainer" AS s
INNER JOIN "User" AS u ON s."AuthorId" = u."Id"
WHERE s."AuthorId" = 1
```

User table:

```
[Table("User")]
public class UserRto
{
        [Key] public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required] public string Nickname { get; set; }
        public string? Email { get; set; }
        [Required] public byte[] PasswordHash { get; set; }
        [Required] public byte[] PasswordSalt { get; set; }
        public string? Name { get; set; }
        public string? Description { get; set; }
        public string? LinkInBio { get; set; }
        public int MedalsAmount { get; set; }
        public string? AvatarUrl { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public bool? IsVerifiedProfile { get; set; }
        public bool? IsAuthorOfQualityContent { get; set; }
        public bool IsInShadowBan { get; set; }
        public DateTime RegistrationDateTime { get; set; }

        public string? PhoneNumberPrefix { get; set; }
        public string? PhoneNumber { get; set; }
        public bool PhoneNumberVerefied { get; set; }
        public string? TelegramId { get; set; }
        public string? TelegramVerifyingChatId { get; set; }
        public string? AccountHeaderUrl { get; set; }

        public List<FriendInvitationRto> FriendInvitationsSent { get; set; }

        public List<FriendInvitationRto> FriendInvitationsReceived { get; set; }

        public List<UserFriendRto> FirstFriends { get; set; }

        public List<UserFriendRto> SecondFriends { get; set; }

        public List<StoryContentRefRto> ViewedStories { get; set; }

        public StoryContainerRto StoryContainer { get; set; }
}
```

Story table:

```
[Table("StoryContainer")]
public class StoryContainerRto
{
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public int AuthorId { get; set; }

        public UserRto Author { get; set; }

        public List<StoryContentRefRto> Items { get; set; }
}
```

How do I complete the request? I understand that the fact is that 3 columns of "Id" come from three tables. But at the same time, if you look at the request generated by EF itself, then there are also 2 "Ids". How do I execute such a request correctly?

https://makolyte.com/ef-core-select-queries-involving-multiple-table/

There is an example of code using INNER JOIN like mine. I do not know why the same approach does not work for me

I also applied the AS operator to all the "Id" columns, but in that case I get this error:

> The required column 'Id' was not present in the results of a 'FromSql' operation

Comment: Please read the [Limitations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/sql-queries#limitations) section of EF Core documentation for SQL queries. Your query is breaking all three rules described there.

Comment: I thik, your problem is not several "Id" column in query. Possible, query returns more then 1 record with the same StoryContainer.Id. For example, try change LEFT JOIN to User  table to INNER JOIN (Story has 1 author?), LEFT JOIN ""StoryContentRefRtoUserRto"" as whoView  - not used, may be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem using a direct SQL query to the database, and then analyzed the information myself

```
List<StoryRto> friendsStories = new();

        using (NpgsqlCommand command = (NpgsqlCommand)(_context as PotokContext)!.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = $@"SELECT s.*, scr.*, u.*, whoView.""ViewedId"" as ""IViewThis""
                    FROM ""Stories"" as s
                    INNER JOIN ""StoryContentRefs"" as scr ON scr.""StoryId"" = s.""Id""
                    INNER JOIN ""User"" as u ON u.""Id"" = s.""AuthorId""
                    LEFT JOIN ""StoryContentRefRtoUserRto"" as whoView ON whoView.""ViewedId"" = 1 AND whoView.""ViewedStoriesId"" = scr.""Id"" 
                    WHERE s.""AuthorId"" IN (
                        SELECT u.""Id""
                        FROM ""UserFriend"" as f, ""User"" as u
                        WHERE
                            CASE
                                WHEN f.""FirstUserFriendId"" = 1
                                THEN f.""SecondUserFriendId"" = u.""Id""
                                WHEN f.""SecondUserFriendId"" = 1
                                THEN f.""FirstUserFriendId"" = u.""Id""
                            END
                    )
                    AND scr.""CreateTimestamp"" >= NOW() - '1 day'::INTERVAL
                    AND scr.""IsDelete"" = false
                    LIMIT {count}
                    OFFSET {skipCount}";

            (_context as PotokContext)!.Database.OpenConnection();

            using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        // Stories table
                        int storyId = reader.GetInt32(0);
                        int authorId = reader.GetInt32(1);

                        // StoryContentRefs table
                        int scrId = reader.GetInt32(2);
                        int scrStoryId = reader.GetInt32(3);
                        string scrStoryContentRef = reader.GetString(4);
                        bool scrIsDelete = reader.GetBoolean(5);
                        DateTime scrCreateTimestamp = reader.GetDateTime(6);

                        // UserTable
                        int userId = reader.GetInt32(7);
                        string userNickname = reader.GetString(8);
                        string? userEmail = reader.IsDBNull(9) ? null : reader.GetString(9);
                        // password hash and salt will not be included
                        string? userName = reader.IsDBNull(12) ? null : reader.GetString(12);
                        string? userDescription = reader.IsDBNull(13) ? null : reader.GetString(13);
                        string? userLinkInBio = reader.IsDBNull(14) ? null : reader.GetString(14);
                        int userMedalsAmount = reader.GetInt32(15);
                        string? userAvatarUrl = reader.IsDBNull(16) ? null : reader.GetString(16);
                        bool userIsDeleted = reader.GetBoolean(17);
                        bool? userIsVerifiedProfile = reader.IsDBNull(18) ? null : reader.GetBoolean(18);
                        DateTime userRegistrationDateTime = reader.GetDateTime(19);
                        bool? userIsAuthorOfQualityContent = reader.IsDBNull(20) ? null : reader.GetBoolean(20);
                        string? userPhoneNumber = reader.IsDBNull(21) ? null : reader.GetString(21);
                        string? userPhoneNumberPrefix = reader.IsDBNull(22) ? null : reader.GetString(22);
                        bool userPhoneNumberVerified = reader.GetBoolean(23);
                        string? userTelegramId = reader.IsDBNull(24) ? null : reader.GetString(24);
                        string? userTelegramVerifyingChatId = reader.IsDBNull(25) ? null : reader.GetString(25);
                        bool userIsInShadowBan = reader.GetBoolean(26);
                        string? userAccountHeaderUrl = reader.IsDBNull(27) ? null : reader.GetString(27);

                        // WhoViewStory relation
                        int? iViewThis = reader.IsDBNull(28) ? null : reader.GetInt32(28);

                        UserRto user = new()
                        {
                            Id = userId,
                            Nickname = userNickname,
                            Email = userEmail,
                            Name = userName,
                            Description = userDescription,
                            LinkInBio = userLinkInBio,
                            MedalsAmount = userMedalsAmount,
                            AvatarUrl = userAvatarUrl,
                            IsDeleted = userIsDeleted,
                            IsVerifiedProfile = userIsVerifiedProfile,
                            RegistrationDateTime = userRegistrationDateTime,
                            IsAuthorOfQualityContent = userIsAuthorOfQualityContent,
                            PhoneNumber = userPhoneNumber,
                            PhoneNumberPrefix = userPhoneNumberPrefix,
                            PhoneNumberVerefied = userPhoneNumberVerified,
                            TelegramId = userTelegramId,
                            TelegramVerifyingChatId = userTelegramVerifyingChatId,
                            IsInShadowBan = userIsInShadowBan,
                            AccountHeaderUrl = userAccountHeaderUrl
                        };

                        List<UserRto> viewed = new();
                        if (iViewThis != null) viewed.Add(user);

                        StoryContentRefRto storyContentRef = new()
                        {
                            Id = scrId,
                            StoryId = scrStoryId,
                            ContentRefs = scrStoryContentRef,
                            IsDelete = scrIsDelete,
                            CreateTimestamp = scrCreateTimestamp,
                            Viewed = viewed
                        };

                        if (friendsStories.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id == scrStoryId) == null)
                        {
                            // Create new
                            StoryRto story = new()
                            {
                                Id = storyId,
                                AuthorId = authorId,
                                Author = user,
                                Items = new() { storyContentRef }
                            };

                            friendsStories.Add(story);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            // Add to existing
                            StoryRto story = friendsStories.First(e => e.Id == scrStoryId);
                            story.Items.Add(storyContentRef);
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
                }
            }
        }
```